# MapControl.ActualCamera doesn't seem to always contain correct data

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm working on a UWP project where I render 3D content on top of a tilted BingMaps map.

I'm rendering my 3d content using directx in a seperate (partially transparent) control that lies on top of the map. So it's not rendered within or as part of the mapcontrol or anything, it's completely seperate.

I made methods that transfer the geo/gps coordinates to the 3d coordinate system I use in Directx, and I make the camera in directx match the map's camera.

But the problem is, the camera data I retrieve from the mapcontrol doesn't always seem to be correct, or at least not up to date.

I use these properties: MapControl.ActualCamera.Location.Position, MapControl.Center.Location.Position, and MapControl.ActualCamera.FieldOfView.

Are these perhaps not the best ones to get the actual current camera data?
If so, which ones should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The camera object isn't currently defined to allow you to completely replicate the full projection matrix used, so I don't think you'll be able to render 3D content that completely matches. Aerial and Road mode use different projections (Mercator plane vs. Globe) and you can't reconstruct the camera look-at vector from the center location property without knowing the map projection and terrain surface values.

Comment: I actually already have it matching. We always use the flat map (dunno what it's called), and using trial and error I found out what projection is used. The problem is that the data I get is sometimes outdated (as in, I move the camera, and even after the camera has stopped moving, the data I get is still from somewhere during the move, rather than the current position). This results in a slight delay (sometimes) when moving the camera, and sometimes an offset.